# how to Update the XMl value and write back using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have a query about updating a node value using Linq,

For example I have to update

```
<Student>
  <studentdetail>
    <studentname>test</studentname>
    <libraryid>hem001</libraryid>
  </studentdetail>
</Student>
```

In the above XML I want to change the value of Student name "test" to something else like "Undertest".

Comment: XML 
<Student>
  <studentdetail>
    <studentname>test</studentname>
    <libraryid>hem001</libraryid>
  </studentdetail>
</Student>

Answer (score 1):

This code is a very basic way of doing what you want.

```
        //there are obviously better ways of "loading" the xml
        var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse("<Student> <studentdetail> <studentname>test</studentname> <libraryid>hem001</libraryid> </studentdetail></Student>");

        //this will only work IF the studentname node exists (the .Single() blows up if it's not there)
        xmlDocument.Descendants("studentname").Single().SetAttributeValue("studentname", "Undertest");
```

You will need the following references:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Futher reading:
http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Comment: I am having multiple sunch thing in one XML i want to update by searching certain element and the only update, yes i need to load the XML that was just an example

Comment: once you have the XDocument, you can use linq on it - from n in xmlDocument.Descendants where n.Name=="studentname" for example

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

[xElement.SetAttributeValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use SingleOrDefault().

And I believe alexjamesbrown you should wrote SetElementValue not SetAttributeValue.

Also you can do it like this:
SingleOrDefault().Value == "replacement string".

Best regards